# Can we add text or color to specific dates in md-calendar by angular material?

Tags: angularjs, date, datepicker, angularjs-scope, angular-material

I want to display some dates in red color like for which data is not available in  an array or database.
Is it possible like through css,angular controller or some other functionality?

Comment: can you clear it more for me ?
 some dates in red color like for which data is not available in an array or database??